# Adding run-time shared library search-path to executable at compile-time | clang | Ubuntu

Tags: clang, ubuntu-14.04, x86-64, gold-linker

An executable I'm compiling needs the `rpath` to a library file at runtime. Currently, I'm compiling the executable with,

```
clang -O3 -mllvm -polly -mllvm -polly-target=gpu vector_add.c -lGPURuntime -ldl
```

And then using either of the following methods to provide the `rpath`,

1. Adding it to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
2. Using `patchelf --set-rpath $RPATH a.out`

I need a method to indicate the `rpath` in the `clang ....` command itself.

I'm running clang5.0.0-svn(7cf8dd5ce168bed45b57e019149e33300c56f94b) and llvm-svn(85f508cd9dba8a982471d98c4f649fb0d63f3451) with ld.gold in Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64.

Thank You !

Answer (score 2):

Use `clang ... -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/run-time/library's/dir/`. It's a `gcc` style option that works in clang too.